# Xcode 14.3.1: viewIsAppearing: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiviewcontroller-lifecycle

```
final class Foo: long chain of derivation leading to UIViewController {
    override func viewIsAppearing(_ animated: Bool) {
        // ...
        super.viewIsAppearing(animated)
    }
}
```

Xcode 14.3.1: viewIsAppearing: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Deployment target is 13.0

How would I get to override viewIsAppearing?
[image: no results for viewIsAppearing]

[image: Xcode 14.3.1]

Comment: See [Swift poor man's replacement for __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED: How to check if I'm compiling code from Xcode 15 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589871/swift-poor-mans-replacement-for-iphone-os-version-max-allowed-how-to-check-i) for a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I get to override viewIsAppearing

You would need to be running Xcode version 15 or later. This method has not yet been introduced in Xcode 14, which is what you're using.

Comment: Seems like the ticket. Bonus question while I;m checking that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589871/how-to-check-if-im-compiling-code-from-xcode-15-beta

Answer (score 1):

If supporting Xcode below 15 is still required for some reason, it's possible to include the header, since the method has actually been available (but not included in the SDK) since iOS 13.

You just need to include the following Objective-C either directly for Objective-C code, or in your bridging header to use it in Swift. (If you don't have one, make a new bridging header with this in it.)

```objectivec
#import "Availability.h"

#if defined(__IPHONE_17_0)
#warning "The iOS 17+ SDK already has viewIsAppearing:"
#else

@import UIKit;

@interface UIViewController (UpcomingLifecycleMethods)

- (void)viewIsAppearing:(BOOL)animated API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0), tvos(13.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos);

@end
#endif
```

Credit to https://liamnichols.eu/2023/06/12/view-is-appearing.html for pointing out this solution.