# Swift poor man's replacement for __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED: How to check if I'm compiling code from Xcode 15 beta?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to check if I'm compiling code from Xcode 15 beta?
Is there a swift version check I can do to make sure

```
override func viewIsAppearing(_ animated: Bool) {
}
```

Checking for ios version is useless on release version of Xcode 14.3.1 :
[image]

Comment: Test code availability is iOS 13 version.

Comment: Makes no sense. `viewIsAppearing` is not a Swift feature. It's an iOS feature. Knowing what swift version you're using would not help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `viewIsAppearing` was made public starting with Xcode 15 but is flagged as being available since iOS 13.0, you need a compile-time check to determine whether the code should be included or not depending on whether you are building your project with Xcode 14 or Xcode 15.

With Objective-C code you can use:

```objectivec
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 170000
- (void)viewIsAppearing:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewIsAppearing:animated];
}
#endif
```

This verifies whether the Base SDK is iOS 17 or later. But unfortunately that doesn't work with Swift code.

One Swift solution would to use the `#if swift(>=X)` compiler directive where "X" is the version of Swift being used with Xcode 15.

```swift
#if swift(>=5.9)
    override func viewIsDisplaying(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewIsDisplaying(animated)
    }
#endif
```

Xcode 14.3 is using Swift version 5.8. Xcode 15.0 (Beta) is using 5.9.

If your app has a deployment target of iOS 12 or earlier then you do need to also add the `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` line.

```swift
#if swift(>=5.9) // Only include this code in Xcode 15 or later
    @available(iOS 13.0, *) // Only apply this for iOS 13.0 or later
    override func viewIsDisplaying(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewIsDisplaying(animated)
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Btw you seem to have guessed the swift version bundled with Xcode 15 right also.